# Can't get the input to show on click of icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently practicing using just vanilla JavaScript to program a website. At the moment, I am making a website where clicking on the fingerprint icon triggers an input to show for the user to key in the password. This is the code I have tried, some of which I adapted from https://gomakethings.com/how-to-show-and-hide-elements-with-vanilla-javascript/.

Despite that, I can't make it work. Please can you help fix the code.

### Code

```js
var show = function(elem) {
  elem.style.display = 'block';
};

var hide = function(elem) {
  elem.style.display = 'none';
};
var toggle = function(elem) {
  elem.classList.toggle('wash');
};

// Listen for click events
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  // Make sure clicked element is our toggle
  if (!event.target.classList.contains('wash')) return;

  // Prevent default link behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get the content
  var content = document.querySelector(event.target.hash);
  if (!content) return;

  // Toggle the content
  toggle(content);

}, false);
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #e0e4ec
}

html {
  background: #556c9a
}

.keys {
  text-align: center;
}

.fa-fingerprint {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h2 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.press:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.type {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/923b4d30ed.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <h1>Pineapple</h1>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="keys">
    <span class="press"><i class="fas fa-fingerprint"></i><h2>Log In</h2></span>
    <span class="type"><input placeholder="Password"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do in regular JS. Target and id and toggle display state.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("my");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
 h1{
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  color:#e0e4ec
}
html{
  background: #556c9a
}
.keys{
  text-align:center;

}
.fa-fingerprint{
  text-align:center;
  padding-left:2%;
  padding-right:2%;
  font-size:3rem;
}
h2{
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}
.press:hover{
  color:yellow;
}
.type{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/923b4d30ed.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <h1>Pineapple</h1>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="keys">
      <span class="press"  onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fas fa-fingerprint"></i><h2>Log In</h2></span>
      <span class="type" id="my"><input  placeholder="Password"></span>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked:) Seems like there's multiple ways to go about doing it

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you need to add an `onclick()` method to your `<span>` containing the input box you want to show, which once clicked will change the display property from **none** to **block**.

You can view the solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ShaneCreedon/3bsfLt0x/12/).

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked:) Seems like there's multiple ways to go about doing it

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can do this in a simple way by just checking the property of `block` and `none`.

1. `input` type is self closing element you don't need to add `</input>` at the end.
2. You need to set the `display` property to the `input` type and based on the click event you can `toggle` on the condition.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var type = document.getElementById('inputType'); // the type you want to hide/show
  if (type.style.display !== 'none') {
    type.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    type.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #e0e4ec
}

html {
  background: #556c9a
}

.keys {
  text-align: center;
}

.fa-fingerprint {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h2 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.press:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/923b4d30ed.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<h1>Pineapple</h1>

<body>
  <div class="keys">
    <span class="press"><i class="fas fa-fingerprint"></i><h2>Log In</h2></span>
    <span id="inputType" style="display:none;"><input placeholder="Password"/></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked:) Seems like there's multiple ways to go about doing it

Comment: Cheers! you can upvote if you think if it is worth doing it! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to the `.press` class to toggle between setting the `<input>`'s display to `none` and `block`.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('press')[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
  var input = document.getElementsByClassName('type')[0];
  input.style.display = (input.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #e0e4ec
}

html {
  background: #556c9a
}

.keys {
  text-align: center;
}

.fa-fingerprint {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h2 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.press:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/923b4d30ed.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <h1>Pineapple</h1>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="keys">
    <span class="press"><i class="fas fa-fingerprint"></i><h2>Log In</h2></span>
    <span class="type" style="display: none;"><input placeholder="Password"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked:) Seems like there's multiple ways to go about doing it.